# Does the pullback of a covering space correspond to the pullback of the corresponding representation of $\pi_1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, general-topology, covering-spaces

In other words, suppose you have a degree $n$ covering space $C\rightarrow X$ corresponding to some (equivalence class of) representation $\pi_1(X)\rightarrow S_n$. Suppose you have any continuous map $f : Y\rightarrow X$, then does the cover $C\times_X Y\rightarrow Y$ correspond to the (equivalence class of) representation $\pi_1(Y)\stackrel{f_*}{\longrightarrow}\pi_1(X)\rightarrow S_n$? (with suitably chosen base points, and assuming $X,Y$ are path connected).

I feel like this should be the case, and it is the case in every example I've worked out, though I can't seem to find this fact anywhere.

If this is false, are there suitable, hopefully tame requirements on $X,Y,f$ for this to be true?

Comment: It is true. It is instructive to work out the details. Alternatively this question would receive a good answer at Mathstackexchange.

Comment: You might want to add local path connectedness.

Comment: You also want to equip your spaces with distinguished base points.

Comment: You can avoid the base points if you use the description of covering **maps of spaces** in terms of covering **morphisms of groupoids**, as described in my book "Topology and Groupoids". This applies in particular to pullbacks.